# batch script: loop and labels

Tags: multithreading, batch-file, wget, simultaneous-calls

I am trying to make a script (batch in windows) that download 5 text files using wget, and do some operations to each one, so I am thinking to do this with a loop just like this

```
set i=0
:begin
set /a i=%i%+1
if %i% equ 5 exit
wget ".....file1.txt"
goto operations

:operations
stuff
stuff
goto begin
```

- operation consist of getting infromation from the text using grep and sed and saving it to text

well, it should work, but this will take a lot of time, I want the batch to do it in an efficient way, because in this way it will download one (take some time) and will do the opeartions.
What I want to do is to make it a multi threaded, I mean to make it do these 5 files (download+operations) simultaneously.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you made the actual process of wget + processing a separate batch file, you can then "start" the batch file which will spawn it as a sub process and continue on in your main batch file eg.

```
batchfile1.cmd
<do something really long>

batchfile2.cmd

for %%N in (a b c d e f g) do start batchfile1.cmd %%n
```

you'll end up with a-g running all at the same time - however you cant easily then tell when all have finished.

Comment: is there a way to call a label 5 times , maybe like start :label & start label ---- ?

Comment: No.. a batch file itself is single threaded, hence you need to spawn other batch files (or call the same one with other parameters and bounce it round internally as appropriate)